# Getting an average grade from a database

Tags: mysql

I'm making a quiz system, and i'm working on displaying an average grade for the user.
So for example If I have table like this:

```
    +-----------+-------------+-------------------+
    |userid     | user_score  |number_of_questions|
    +-----------+-------------+-------------------+
    |  1        |      10     |        10         |   
    |  1        |      10     |        10         |
    |  1        |      10     |        10         |
    |  1        |      10     |        10         |
    |  1        |      9      |        10         |
    |  1        |      4      |        5          |
    |  1        |      4      |        5          |
    |  1        |      5      |        5          |
    |  1        |      5      |        5          |
    +-----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Is there anyway of getting an average grade?

EDIT: I have changed the grades from letters to scores, as I have been made aware that you cannot get averages for non numeric values.

How would I go about doing a query to get the average of user score  for both number of questions?

Comment: Anyone else see [tag:mysqli] and almost edit it to [tag:mysql]?

Comment: If I got B and B+, what is my average grade?

Comment: @RoboRobok Oooo thats a good one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re asking for the query, so the simple answer would be

```
Select avg(user_score) 
From {table_name}
Where {your criteria}
Group by user_id
```

However, your client will be rather disappointed with your calculations—getting 5 points out of 5 and 100 out of 100 is quite different than averaging 5 and 100!

So I would suggest using percentage instead of raw score:

```
Select avg(user_score/number_of_questions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the grades to integers using `ASCII()`, then convert the average back to grades using `CHAR()`.

```
SELECT CHAR(ROUND(AVG(ASCII(`grade`)-65))+65) FROM table
```

Please note this doesn't take the `+` into account. You'd first have to decide the numeric value of a `+` on a grade.

Comment: Ooo take a look at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49213945/getting-an-average-grade-from-a-database#comment85433441_49213945)